# How to set environment variables for executable file

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I recently installed vcgencmd on my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu ARM64;
but I can't use vcgencmd command in `.sh` file without writing `PATH=$PATH` in it.
I can use it normally on terminal.
I tried adding

```
export "PATH=/opt/vc/bin:$PATH"
```

to `/etc/profile.d/vc.sh` but nothing's changed.

Is there any way to apply `PATH` variable to every executable file I run?

Comment: Have you re-logined after adding the variable to the **/etc/profile.d/vc.sh** file ?

Comment: that should be `export PATH="/opt/vc/bin:$PATH"`. another option is to provide the full path of your `vcgencmd` command within .sh script which I suggest this way.

Comment: @Parsa I tried both rebooting and re-loginning after that

Comment: @αғsнιη I tried using export command right before executing some .sh file on bash, but it didn't work. also, providing full path of vcgencmd would work, but that would be an inconvenience

Comment: @tmvkrpxl0 exporting the PATH out of script would only apply for the current local shell you are in other than for the script you execute, either move the export into the script before the command `vcgencmd` you are executing or as I said use full path of your command which it preferred